# Getting a CSS value from $(this) in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-animate

So I have working code that animates a BG image via a plugin. This is a general solution though where each element in the class has the same BG image; I'm using a sprite with a unique image for each column of my navigation bar. THe code is thusly:

```
$('#nav a')
.mouseover(function(){
    $(this).stop().animate(
        {backgroundPosition:"(0 -250px)"}, 
        {duration:500})
    })
.mouseout(function(){
    $(this).stop().animate(
        {backgroundPosition:"(0 0)"}, 
        {duration:500})
    })
```

This works great, so I can set a Y-offset for each element, but each link has it's own x-offset that won't change/be animated at all. Example CSS:

```
li.downloads a {
    background:url(img/navsprite.png) repeat -318px -9px;
}
```

I want to roll the `-318px -9px` to something like `-318px 200px`, but for another element I'd want to change `-482px -9px` to `-482px 200px`. Only the Y-offset should change, but I don't know the syntax of jQuery well enough to pull that value from the CSS of $(this) element and put it into the animate parameters. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the background position like this:

```
$(this).css("background-position");
```

You can get both values in an array like this:

```
var bgpos = $(this).css("background-position").split(" ");
```

Which allows you to access both values with `bgpos[0]` and `bgpos[1]`.

Comment: And are both the X and Y attributes further selectable? Ideally what I'd want was to say "Change to BackgrounPosition:($x -200px)" or something similar

Comment: @Alex: See my updated text. You could refer to both via array-entries following a split on the value.

Comment: at that point, I think you need to use regex to get your values

Comment: @Mike: Not necessarily. Note that I simply split the string into two parts, and accessed both values via indexes in the resulting array.

Answer (score 0):

There is a css property background-position-x. This is only available in IE however, so is probably not a valid solution for your problem.
jQuery does support relative animations by specifying f.e. +=50px;
No idea if it works, but you could try the following code:

```
$('#nav a')
.mouseover(function(){
    $(this).stop().animate(
        {backgroundPosition:"(+=0 -250px)"}, 
        {duration:500})
    })
.mouseout(function(){
    $(this).stop().animate(
        {backgroundPosition:"(+=0 0)"}, 
        {duration:500})
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery.fn.getBackgroundxPosition = function(val) {
    var position = $(this).css('background-position');
    var position_array=val.split(' ');
    var x_pos = position_array[0];

    if(typeof(position) === 'undefined'){ //IE fix
        x_pos = $(this).css('background-position-x');
    }
return x_pos;
};
```

I think this will work (not tested)